# Reason to mention scope id in link local address of ipv6

Tags: ipv6

In Ipv6,we have the link local address and the scope_id appended to it. Since link local address is derived from MAC address(which is unique), why is it required for us to mention the scope_id too in the call (which is basically the interface_id like eth0 ) when the link local address itself is unique???

Comment: The MAC address is not always unique, Sun hardware was quite frequent to use the same address for every NIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link-local addresses don't have to be derived from a MAC address, and every link-local address can be valid on every interface at the same time. And each combination of link and address can have a different meaning, so you always need to specify the link / scope.

Comment: Does anybody know if scope_id is host or network order byte ?